# How the required amount of CPU is calculated in YARN with Dominant Resource fairness by an application in submission time?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

In **YARN DRF**, how an application knows during job submission state about required amount of CPU?

NOTE: I understand that memory requirement is calculated for mappers (based on input split and container memory settings) and reducer (based on # of reducers & container memory settings.)